# Opening a WMV file with window.open, in firefox; how can I prevent blank window from opening or close after file downloads?

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, window.open, wmv

When you download a file on CNET.com, a message will display on the page to wait a moment and the download will start; if it doesn't, click the link.  That's very similar to the page with which I'm working.

The user clicks a link and this page appears with a similar message to CNETs.  The only difference is the file is a WMV file and it automatically opens and plays.  It works fine in IE.  It's not working correctly in Firefox.  In Firefox, if the user goes Tools->Options->Applications and selects "Use Windows Media Player" for Windows Media Video File, it plays in the external WMP.  If the user uses the WMP plugin, however, the page opens up a blank window and then plays the video in the external WMP.

```
window.open("test.wmv");
```

Is there a way to prevent it from opening a window or how can I close the window after the wmv is downloaded and played?

Thank you very much.

**Update**

I found a link, [here](http://www.mvyradio.com/knowledgebase/index.php?sid=465&lang=en&action=artikel&cat=2&id=45&artlang=en), that may be related to this issue.  It states that the blank window is a bug with how Firefox handles the WMP plugin, with respect to ASX files.  The only difference between the link and my question is one file is of type WMV and the other is of type ASX.  The link is dated 2007 and the problem is reported on Firefox 1.5, but perhaps it still has merit.  Maybe Mozilla has not addressed this bug, ever (FYI: I'm using Firefox 9.0.1).

I'm starting to think there is no direct solution.  I can put a disclaimer, inform the user to turn off the WMP plugin in Firefox.  Would a modal window or iFrame be helpful?